# How to pass same test data into multiple feature files

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java

Q : How to pass same test data into multiple feature files scenario/examples

Scenario : I need to use couple of test data values in many feature files as its common across the multiple scenarios. Currently 'm putting it in examples but whenever need to change test data, have to keep updating test data in all required feature files.

Is there any way to keep common test data in .properties/.feature/txt/excel file so that I can just change test data in one file(.properties/.feature/txt/excel) and this test data will be picked-up by my respective feature files during execution?

Comment: Anyone can answer?

Comment: You could delegate the data to the step definition or a helper method, rather than the step in the feature file. Instead of "Given an account with number 12345678 and currency dollars and balance 10" -> Given a non-empty account" (or something) and then set the values in a step definition or method "createAccount(12345678, dollars, 10)"; making sure to call the same method everywhere.